# WinRT Extract Thumbnail from RAW image format

Tags: image-processing, windows-runtime

I have a RAW image(from Nokia D5000, so .NEF file extension) on my Windows Phone(8.1).

I want to write a program that takes the image and gets the embedded JPG file from the RAW image format. I also will need to handle any RAW file, so file extensions from other cameras will also have to work.

Is there any existing library out there for WinRT? I searched and didn't really find anything for WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT for Windows Phone does not include the RAW codecs necessary to parse the image format. Therefore, the only way to manipulate and use RAW files is to convert a third party library such as dcraw into a Window Runtime Component.